# Does requestLocationUpdates() trigger an immediate update request?

Tags: android, gps, locationmanager

Does [`LocationManager.requestLocationUpdates()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html#requestLocationUpdates(long,%20float,%20android.location.Criteria,%20android.app.PendingIntent)) trigger an immediate request for location update, or will it wait for the initial interval before requesting the first update?

If the latter, would it be appropriate to trigger both `requestSingleUpdate()` and `requestLocationUpdates()` one after the other to make sure that an immediate request is made?

Answer (score 0):

As per Doc, both will take some time to get the location, So you can try `getLastKnownLocation(String)`, it will give immediately.

> The requestLocationUpdates() and requestSingleUpdate() register the
>   current activity to be updated periodically by the named provider, or
>   by the provider matching the specified Criteria, with location and
>   status updates.
>
> It may take a while to receive the first location update. If an
>   immediate location is required, applications may use the
>   getLastKnownLocation(String) method.

[Reference](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html#requestLocationUpdates(long,%20float,%20android.location.Criteria,%20android.app.PendingIntent))

Comment: I understand that the _result_ won't be immediate, but I was wondering if the process of getting the result will be started immediately by `requestLocationUpdates()`, or if that process will only start after the `minTime` interval has passed.

Comment: It should start immediately, but I never seen any doc that it will start immediately. But you will get the location based on **Criteria** what you supplied.